# Finding the matrix representation of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I encountered the following problem but don't know how to solve it.

Let $f$ be a linear operator of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$
$$
f: \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} 
\mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
-a & -6a - 3b - 6c \\
3a + b + 2c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
find the matrix representation of the linear transformation of $~f~$ with respect to
$$
\mathcal{B} = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0     
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
My idea was determine $f$ of $\mathcal{B}_1$, $\mathcal{B}_2$, $\mathcal{B}_3$, $\mathcal{B}_4$ and add all these matrices together but I think this is wrong.

Comment: Please do not misspell words in the title; they make searching difficult. If your chosen blank generic title is already in use, then consider using a **more informative** title instead of misspelling it.

Comment: In particular, correct spelling is *linear*, not *lineair*

Comment: Evaluate $f$ at each basis vector. Express the result using the basis.

Comment: Am i right that the matrix representation also has to be a 2x2 matrix?

Comment: No, you are wrong. What is the dimension of your space?

Comment: dimension 4, i was confused by the fact that f operates on the 2x2 matrices so i thought that the matrix representation also had to be a 2x2 matrix. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion arises because we are used to the elements of a basis being a list (a $1$-dimensional array), but because they are matrices, they are naturally given a double index $E_{ij}$, i.e. a $2$-dimensional array. So, we have to provide a linear ordering of the basis in order to order the rows and columns and use the usual tools. The standard way is to give row precedence, i.e. to sort by double indices by lexicographic order:
$$
(1, 1) < (1, 2) < (2, 1) < (2, 2).
$$

---

With basis of matrix units $\mathcal{B} = \{E_{11}, E_{12}, E_{21}, E_{22}\}$, in order to represent the operator by a matrix, we have to evaluate $f(E_{ij})$ and express each as a linear combination of $\mathcal{B}$ again.
For instance, with $E_{11}$ the coefficients are $a=1$ and $b=c=d=0$, so
$$
f(E_{11}) = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -6 \\
3 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
= -E_{11} - 6E_{12} +3E_{21}.
$$
Hence, the first column of the $4 \times 4$ matrix representing $f$ will be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ -6 \\ 3 \\ 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can work out the other columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i now understand it.